# How to make layout center even when minimize?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, layout

I have a layout problem on my site..

I develop using MVC for it..

the layout will become a bit strange when I minimize it or I using smaller resolution..

my pc using 1366 x 768 resolution..

if I'm not minimize it, it will be okay..

but when I'm trying to make the browser smaller, it has a gap on the right..

I want to center it like www.bluenile.com website..

thank you..

Images:

before I minimize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSEQS.png

after I minimize: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gek87.png

Thank you guys!

this is my layout:

```
<body class="body">
<table class="wrapper" style="width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Partial("Header")
            <table class="main" width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 0px;"
                align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">@Html.Partial("TopMenu")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" width="100%">@RenderBody()
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidepadding">
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.Partial("ResourcesCentre")
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidepadding">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sidepadding">
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.Partial("Networks")
                    </td>
                    <td class="sidepadding">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="1015" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: 0px;"
                align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 5px; height: 1px;">
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.Partial("Footer")
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 5px; height: 1px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this is my style:

```
    .body
    {
background-image: url('/Content/images/Diamond_Background_Blue.png');
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: "Gotham Book", "Gotham Bold", "Gotham Light", "Gotham Thin", Verdana, Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
}

    .wrapper
    {
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After I check my css, there is a css code on navigation that make it run: *position: relative*.. I remove that code and now the layout okay already..

Thanks guys for your help.. :)

Comment: Pictures don't tell the whole story. Post your code.

Comment: i've already post the code.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The trick to centering an element is to give it a width and left right margins of `auto`. E.g. `margin: 0 auto`. For more help, post an example of your code.

Comment: Do you mean that the white gap appears to the right when you scroll to the right? In that case, put a min-width on the wrapper equal to the width of the inner contents, such as `min-width: 1015px;`

Comment: I've tried, Ralph.. but still same.. got gap on the right side.. ;( anyway, thanks..

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to give the full picture. Post a link to your actual page, or reconstruct it over at jsFiddle or CodePen so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS just add this line on your page ,containers, wrappers etc.

```
{
  margin:0 auto; 
}
```

Here's a reference, [How to Center a Website With CSS](http://buildinternet.com/2008/11/how-to-center-a-website-with-css/). If you want to test it to different screen resolution you could test it [here](https://quirktools.com/screenfly/). Hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto` to body and give it a `width: 80%` or something. And to make your page fluid, use width in `%` and not px

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RRPM4/1/)

Comment: My bad, I forgot to tell you that in the second `table` inside `table.wrapper` you have `<table width="1015" border="0" ...`. Remove `width="1015"`. After you remove that, It must work fine.